# implementing logger in ruby script

Tags: ruby

This is a ruby script which i am using to log my status.

```
require 'logger'

log = Logger.new( 'log.txt', 'daily' )

log.debug "Once the log becomes at least one"
log.debug "day old, it will be renamed and a"
log.debug "new log.txt file will be created."
```

Now i want to make a new ruby file in which i want to include logger it can be like this

```
module Logging

  def logger
    Logging.logger
  end

  def self.logger
    @logger ||= Logger.new(STDOUT)
  end

end
```

But i am not able to understand this so can anyone explain it.

my requirement is like there are lots of ruby script file i want to put a logger in module and include that in every file than write log in log file it can be warning it can be a info or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better alternative would be:

```
module Logging

def logger
@logger ||= Logger.new(STDOUT)
end

end
```

And use it like this

```
class MyLoggingClient
include Logging

#Now you have access to the method `logger` and the instance variable `@logger`.

end
```

Comment: Some what near to my question now can you tell me if i included Logger.new(STDOUT) this what does it mean

Answer (score 0):

What I can gather from your question is the code works... you're just confused on what it does... if that's correct then to explain, when you `inculde Logging` in any of your classes the from anywhere in the classes methods call `logger.log("This is a log message")` it will log that message to the console that started the scripts.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Some what near to my question now can you tell me if i included Logger.new(STDOUT) this what does it mean

Comment: You can include only modules, as mixins. You can read more here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html

Comment: If at the top of a class you write `include Logging` that will then bring in those same methods you defined in the Logging module, and allow you to do `logger.log("This is a log message")` from anywhere in the class you included the Logging module on. When you call `logger.log...` it will then output whatever you wrote in the message to the console. Very handy for debugging. For example you could output to the console a variable halfway through a method. e.g. `logger.log("Trouble Variable: #{the_trouble_variable}")` does that make sense?

Comment: Basically this will help you debug your scripts by being able to output data during script execution.